# Coinbase Advanced trade API connectivity using python3 is not working

Tags: python-3.x, cryptocurrency, coinbase-api

I tried below code based on the coinbase documentaion [coinbase doc](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/advanced-trade-api/docs/rest-api-auth)
The documentation is given for Python2 but i have modified and used it for Python3 because i am trying to connect to advanced trade API in Coinbase [Coinbase Advanced trade doc](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/advanced-trade-api/reference/retailbrokerageapi_getaccounts)

```
import datetime
import time
import hmac
import hashlib
import http.client


secret_key='***'    #hidden
api_key='***'       #hidden

date_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
timestamp=int(time.mktime(date_time.timetuple())) # timestamp should be from UTC time and no decimal allowed

method = "GET" # method can be GET or POST. Only capital is allowed
request_path = 'api/v3/brokerage/accounts'
body=''
message= str(timestamp) + method + request_path + body
signature = hmac.new(secret_key.encode('utf-8'), message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()


headers={
'accept':'application/json',
'CB-ACCESS-KEY': api_key,
'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature
}


conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.coinbase.com")
payload = ''

conn.request("GET", "/api/v3/brokerage/accounts", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

When executing this code i was expecting account details. But i am getting **unauthoried error** and error code 401 as return from API.

I was able to connect to Coinbase Pro API earlier and everything was fine till the merger of coinbase and Coinbase Pro.Now unable to figure out how to connect to the Advanced trade feature in coinbase.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to include error output in the question body. This is preferable to including an image, especially one with such low resolution and lacking context.

Comment: I have removed the image, highlighted the error message and added error code.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I made two updates to get this running.

1. Insert a `/` before `api` in `request_path = '/api/v3/brokerage/accounts'` :)
2. Change the way you generate your `timestamp` to `timestamp = str(int(time.time()))`.

I thought updating your `timestamp` to a string would fix it, but it didn't, so I reverted to the way I was generating it. Maybe someone can tell us why one works and one doesn't. I'll certainly update this post if I figure it out.

Here's the full working code. I kept everything else the same but replaced your comments with mine.

```py
import datetime
import time
import hmac
import hashlib
import http.client

secret_key = '***'  
api_key = '***'  

# This is the first part where you were getting time
#date_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow() 

# And this is the second part where you format it as an integer
#timestamp=int(time.mktime(date_time.timetuple())) 

# I cast your timestamp as a string, but it still doesn't work, and I'm having a hard time figuring out why.
#timestamp=str(int(time.mktime(date_time.timetuple()))) 

# So I reverted to the way that I'm getting the timestamp, and it works
timestamp = str(int(time.time()))

method = "GET"
request_path = '/api/v3/brokerage/accounts' # Added a forward slash before 'api'
body=''
message= str(timestamp) + method + request_path + body
signature = hmac.new(secret_key.encode('utf-8'), message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()


headers={
'accept':'application/json',
'CB-ACCESS-KEY': api_key,
'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature
}


conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.coinbase.com")
payload = ''

conn.request("GET", "/api/v3/brokerage/accounts", payload, headers)
# You were probably troubleshooting, but the above line is redundant and can be simplified to:
# conn.request("GET", request_path, body, headers) 

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is code for Coinbase Pro, not Advanced.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).